# How to make a responsive layout in bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive-design, media-queries

I want to make a layout which looks like this in large screens:-
[image]

And looks like this in medium screens:-
[image]

This is my code:-

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                A
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                    <div>
                        B
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        C
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But this code is not working as expected. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I have made this code for you and try to see if the one you are looking for.
I have made two layouts, one for M-size and one for large size, and each one will display with a different viewport width.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="medium-layout d-block d-lg-none">
      <div class="row ">
                <div class="style-class col-6 one">
                        A - Medium
                </div>
                <div class="style-class  col-6 two">
                        B
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"> 
          <div class="style-class col three">
            C
          </div>
        </div>
   </div>
<!--     /*end of medium and below layout*/ -->
 
<!--   start of large layout -->
  <div class="large-layout d-none d-lg-block">
      <div class="row ">
                <div class="col one">
                        A - Large
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="style-class  row">
                       <div class="style-class col-lg-12 two">
                          B
                      </div>
                      <div class="style-class col-lg-12 three">
                        C
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               
        </div>

<!--     /*start of large layout*/ -->
  </div>
        <!--     /* End of the container */ -->
</div>
```

[look at here](https://codepen.io/youssefkhoukhou/pen/MWXrEPJ)